# Change structure of an array of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6, pivot

I have the following array of arrays:

```
[
  [
     {
        a: "AA", 
        b: "BB"
     },
     {
        a: "AA", 
        c: "CC"
     },
     {
        a: "AA", 
        d: "DD"
     },
     {
        a: "AA", 
        e: "EE"
     }
  ],
  [
     {
        a: "AA_2", 
        b: "BB_2"
     },
     {
        a: "AA_2", 
        c: "CC_2"
     },
     {
        a: "AA_2", 
        d: "DD_2"
     },
     {
        a: "AA_2", 
        e: "EE_2"
     }
  ]
]
```

So it's an array containing two arrays of length 4.

I want to transform it to obtain the following format:

```
[
  {
   b: "BB", c: "CC", d: "DD", e: "EE" 
  },
  {
   b: "BB_2", c: "CC_2", d: "DD_2", e: "EE_2" 
  }
]
```

I want the final array to contain two objects.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you try? Show us code if you tried.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't make it clear what do you really want to filter from the subject array, so I just assume you want to exclude the primary key value with key "a".

```
var a = subject;
var out = ['a'];
var r = [];
for(var i in a){
 var ai = a[i];
 var o = {};
 for(var ii in ai){
   var aii = ai[ii];
   for(var k in aii){
     if(out.indexOf(k) == -1) o[k] = aii[k];
   }
 }
 r.push(o);
}
console.log(r);
```